# Does $(a)=(b)$ imply that $a$ and $b$ are associate in a principal ideal ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative principal ideal ring with identity. Suppose that $a,b\in R$ and $(a)=(b)$. I'd like to know if there always exists $u\in R^\times$ such that $a=bu$.

I know several counterexamples if $R$ is not a principal ideal ring, so I'm a bit curious about whether it holds for principal ideal rings.

Comment: Usually people talk about $PID$, principal ideal domains. These are integral domains, so from $a=xb$ and $b=ya$ you can establish that $a(1-xy)=0$ so that indeed $x,y$ are units. Is there any reason to study non-domains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A PIR is a direct product of PIDs and local PIRs. (This is  well known and can be found in Zariski and Samuel, *Commutative Algebra*, or in Hungerford's paper "[On the structure of principal ideal rings](http://msp.org/pjm/1968/25-3/pjm-v25-n3-p11-p.pdf)"). Now you can draw the conclusion.